# Uniswap graph SVG for specific pairs?

Tags: subgraph, uniswap

I was wondering , how Uniswap is making the graph SVG of the pair ?
is that a feature that i can use also ?
Which API can i use ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG generation is part of the Uniswap v3 smart contract code. The Solidity source file that generates the NFT can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/NFTSVG.sol).

Comment: Thank you. If I deployed my own contract on V2 and I have a UniswapV2Pair Address - can I somehow generate the NFTSVG for that pair ? or the pair must be deployed based on the V3 Smart contract?

Comment: @ofirthedev I don't think so. Functions like `generateSVGImage` and `generateSVG` are declared as `internal`, so they can only be called by v3 contracts if I understand correctly. In additio, you don't have things like ranges and ticks in v2, so lot of the NFT would not make sense for v2 positions.